# Remove the frame, shadow and the title bar of the window

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

How to remove the frame, shadow, and the title bar?

From QT Creator.

Using AutoHotkey L?

[image]

Comment: Please describe in detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://zapodaj.net/images/5a4fbc4da77c2.png

Comment: I cant see the image. I presume you are building a QT app and you don't want window border and title bar. But whats with Autohotkey?

Comment: No. As for the editor window.
http://s8.postimg.org/oq806aw6d/ahkqtframex.png

Comment: please add this screenshot to question.

Comment: Tried this: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/78903-yabt-yet-another-borderless-window-toggle/

Comment: I can not add pictures.
Only link.

Comment: I used this:

There are two errors:
http://s29.postimg.org/tgfnq73qf/qtcreatornoframebugs.png

1. Malfunction of the cursor in some menus and buttons. I do not mind so much, but better to fix it.
2. Transparent, but taking the place of the field to the right and below. locks click.
Do not just stretch the editor window.
I want to change the size of the editor, together with resize another window in the background. Bothered by it at that. For this to mind:
http://s27.postimg.org/dpnn6f5w3/qtinfx.png

Comment: I used this*:
    WinSet, Style, ^0x00C40000, A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this:
WinSet, Style, ^0x00C40000, A

There are two errors:
http://s29.postimg.org/tgfnq73qf/qtcreatornoframebugs.png

1. Malfunction of the cursor in some menus and buttons. I do not mind so much, but better to fix it.
2. Transparent, but taking the place of the field to the right and below. locks click.
   Do not just stretch the editor window.
   I want to change the size of the editor, together with resize another window in the background. Bothered by it at that. For this to mind:
   http://s27.postimg.org/dpnn6f5w3/qtinfx.png

Comment: Try this: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/78903-yabt-yet-another-borderless-window-toggle/ It uses some different window style

Comment: I checked all of the pages. The effect is always with errors.

Comment: How do I use one style a few times, then to change one and drigi. It sometimes starts to work properly. Very weird.

Comment: Solution: The program must be maximized before running the script.